# How to make a custom Back button for jQuery load() content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, back

In one of my php page (Report.php), I am loading its content through jQuery load(). I want to create a "back button" on my php page so that my user can click it to go back pages. **Note**- I am not looking for browser back button.

Here is my php pages -

**report_template.php**

```
//This page query my database and creates a content table<br>
//Table content
<a href="#" onclick="fetchReport(<?php echo $row['report_id']; ?>);">Another Report Link</a>
```

**report.php**

```
<button>Go Back</button> //This button will take user to back (equivalent to window.history.back() )
<div id="rept"> </div>

<script>
jQuery('#rept').load('report_template?id=1');
 
function fetchReport(id){
 jQuery('#rept').load('report_template?id='+id);
}
</script>
```

I am average level skill in jquery/javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of every page start session `session_start();` and set the current page as a `$_SESSION` variable.   IE

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['last_page'] = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; // Or whatever you designate it as
```

Then you can call it in **report.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

<button onClick="window.open(<?= $_SESSION['last_page'] ?>);">Go Back</button> //This button will take user to back (last report page he's seen)
<div id="rept"> </div>

<script>
jQuery('#rept').load('report_template?id=1');
 
function fetchReport(id){
 jQuery('#rept').load('report_template?id='+id);
}
</script>
```

A slightly simpler, yet less reliable way to do it, is to grab the last page the person was on according to PHP `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` This can also include "off server" pages. Also it may better suit your question if the referrer may, in fact, come from "somewhere else" IE:

```
 <button onClick="window.open(<?= $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ?>);">Go Back</button>
```

Comment: $_SESSION variable works good for one step back. Maybe I am not clear in my question so I edited my question. Assume user goes from page1 -> page2 -> page3 -> page4 And now when he click the back button, it should be page3 -> page2  -> page1 (same like browser's back button do)

Comment: @Bips --  Short of writing a tutorial, you can use an `array()` to store all the pages a user visits ..  Like `$_SESSION['history'][0] =  'page1'; $_SESSION['history'][1] =  'page2';`  --  Then set a "current page" as whatever `index` you are on .. `$_SESSION['current_page'] = 2;`  Based on that you should be able to build it out pretty simply.